# Volley library does not connect to 10.0.2.2

Tags: android, android-volley

I have added volley library to my android project. I am using android emulator. I just want to get data from my localhost. Thats why I have set url to http://10.0.2.2/test.php .

But problem is volley does not connect to this address. But in my android emulator I tried this link with google chrome. It is working fine. But if I change the url to google.com or other websites, volley library is working fine. Only http://10.0.2.2/test.php this url is not working in volley but not other browser in Android emulator.

Can anyone tell me is volley library does not support this local host ip 10.0.2.2?

Error:

> com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.io.IOException: Cleartext
>   HTTP traffic to 10.0.2.2 not permitted

Comment: No. Android ver is oreo

Comment: Okay, Is there any error log?

Comment: I just check with on response and interior. If I put other website, on onresponse method show the response

Comment: When you put your URL, What response are you getting?

Comment: Sorry for late reply here is the log (com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.io.IOException: Cleartext HTTP traffic to 10.0.2.2 not permitted)

Comment: Sorry for late reply by me too, I knew it, that it will be this error. Check my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Solution:**

Add this line in your manifest:

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

because I faced the same issue with my php page on Laravel.

It should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        ...
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        ...>
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Let's hope it works.